# I got an error "unable to activate DbContext" while making controller in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I Got an error while creating controller using scaffolding "Unable to resolve service for type, while attempting to activate 'MyWebApplication.Models.MyDbContext' "[Here is the image of my code and error while creating controller using scaffolding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9edM.png)

I want a solution of my problem and I tried everything but unable to resolve. [Here is the image of my code and error while creating controller using scaffolding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKBNf.png)

Comment: Post your code and error as text in the message itself. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or tested. If you search for the error you'll find a *lot* of similar questions. Did you register `MyDbContext` with `AddDbContext` in your Program.Main or Startup class?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information so that we can help you out. To me, it sounds like you have not registered the DbContext with your Dependency Injection and that's why it could not be "activated".

Check if your context is registered with the DI first. If that does not make the  trick, provide more information.

You can register the context by doing something like:

```
    services.addDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((sp, options) => {
        var cnstring = 
  sp.GetRequiredService(IConfiguration).GetConnectionString("default");
    options.UseSqlServer(cnstring);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error screenshot you provided, I replicated the issue *Unable to resolve service for type, while attempting to activate 'MyWebApplication.Models.MyDbContext'*, The issue relates that the DbContext is not registered when using the scaffolding.
My model:

```
 public class Students
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string? Genre { get; set; }
      public string? Name { get; set; }
  }
```

My Dbcontext:

```
public class MyDbcontext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbcontext(DbContextOptions<MyDbcontext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> students { get; set; }
    }
```

When I didn't register MyDbcontext in ConfigureServices:

[image]

The same problem occurs as depicted in the figure:

[image]

When I registered Mydbcontex with ConfigureServices in Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbcontext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbcontext")));
```

The StudentsController be created successfully:

[image]